Conversion from Pytorch to CoreML
I'm trying to convert the parseq model:
https://github.com/baudm/parseq
to the CoreML format. I'm doing this on collab and I'm using this code:
import torch
from PIL import Image
import coremltools as ct
from google.colab import drive
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer

# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True)

# Ensure the correct path to the local repository in Google Drive
local_repo_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/parseq'

# Initialize the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(accelerator='gpu' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu', devices=1)

# Load the model from the local repository
parseq = torch.hub.load(local_repo_path, 'parseq', source='local', pretrained=True)
parseq.trainer = trainer  # Attach the trainer to the model
parseq.eval()

# Get the image size from the model's parameters
img_size = [32, 128]  # Defined image size for the parseq model

# Example input tensor with the correct size
example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, img_size[0], img_size[1])

# Trace the model with example input
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(parseq, example_input)

# Debug: Check the output of the traced model
try:
    out = traced_model(example_input)
    print("Tracing successful. Output shape:", out.shape)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error during tracing:", e)

# Convert the traced model to Core ML
try:
    model = ct.convert(
        traced_model,
        convert_to="mlprogram",
        inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=example_input.shape)],
        debug=True
    )
    print("Conversion to Core ML successful.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error during Core ML conversion:", e)

# Define the path in Google Drive where you want to save the model
drive_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/new_parseq_model.mlpackage'

# Save the converted model to Google Drive
try:
    model.save(drive_path)
    print(f"Model saved to {drive_path}")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error saving the Core ML model:", e)

However, I'm stuck on this error and i don't know how to fix it.
Error during Core ML conversion: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int
It's weird because this model works just fine on my machine.
I tried debugging the forward method but as I said earlier it works just fine and always produces good Tensors (non-None type). And now I'm stuck and don't know what to do.
